# How to show percentage in pie chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *iReport* and *JasperReports*, both in *v4.7*.

I want to show the percentage of each slice in the label. Something like "Option 1 (45.67%)".

After reading many sites I came to the following snippet.

```xml
<piePlot labelFormat="{0} ({2})" legendLabelFormat="{0} ({2})">
    <plot/>
    <itemLabel/>
</piePlot>
```

According to the documentation of *iReport*.

- {0} item name
- {1} value
- {2} percentage

However, when I run the report on *iReport* or *JasperReports* I get only the percentage in the legend area (*legendLabelFormat*) not in label (*labelFormat*) of each slice and, also, the percentage is show as an integer not as a  float.

Somebody knows how to show the percentage in the label and -if possible- with decimal values?

Comment: Have you checked the "Show Labels" checkbox in iReport?

Comment: Yes, This is what I get. [link](http://imageshack.us/f/443/pchart00.png/).

For some reason iReport ignores the _labelFormat="{0} ({2})_

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution here. Remove your lableExpression from the pieDataset, it overwrites your piePlot lables.

```
<pieDataset>
  <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{GENERATION}]]></keyExpression>
  <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUBTOTAL}]]></valueExpression>
</pieDataset>
<piePlot isShowLabels="false" isCircular="true" labelFormat="({2})" legendLabelFormat="{0}">
  <plot/>
  <itemLabel/>
</piePlot>
```